# Why $\forall$ is not a predicate

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

There is a reason why existence can not be a predicate, namely:

1. Let's prove that unicorns exist.
2. It is sufficient to prove that there is an existing unicorn.
3. There are two possibilities: either an existing unicorn exists or it does not.
4. The second possibility is a contradiction: how could an *existing* unicorn not exist? That's the same as saying that a blue ball is not blue.
5. So, unicorns exist.

This argument probably dates back to Kant and the ontological argument of God's existence. It shows that $\exists$ is not a "property" and should be treated in a special way.

My question is why we need $\forall$ as a special symbol. Are there any arguments like the one (for existence) that I mentioned?

I suspect that that text about unicorns could be rewritten using negations and $\forall$, but I don't exactly see how.

Comment: On the philosophical debate about *existence*, see F.Berto, [Existence as a Real Property (2012)](https://books.google.it/books?id=UobUqRMyUawC&pg=PA1).

Comment: According to Frege (but the basic argument is already in Kant) *existence* is not a property of an *object* (an individual) but of a *concept* (a class). Thus, to say that "unicorns do not exists" amounts to say that the class of unicorns is empty. This does not preclude us to use the concept of unicorn, without committing to the existence of individual unicorns.

Comment: Surely this goes back further, to much older ontological arguments.

Comment: Your purported argument amounts to a single line : $\exists x \text {Uni}(x) \lor \lnot \exists x \text {Uni}(x)$ and this is **not** a contradiction but a "tautology".

Comment: 1 and 2 are not premises but only comemnts and 4 is wrong. THus, 5 does not follows.

Comment: "Is existence a predicate?" is a question of philosophy, not mathematics, so it's off-topic on this site. But putting that aside, the "argument" seems like nonsense to me. One way to read line 3 is as Mauro did: "there exists an existing unicorn, or there does not exist an existing unicorn". Neither of these cases seem problematic to me. Another way to read line 3 is "for all existing unicorns U, either U exists or U does not exist." Now if U is an existing unicorn, it would be contradictory for U to not exist. So we can conclude "for all existing unicorns U, U exists". Ok, fine...

Comment: ...I can't conclude from this that unicorns exist. There might just not be any existing unicorns.

Comment: @liaombro. Maybe you will find interesting things in Russell's Principles of Mathematics, §72 "  "All men" is not analyzable into "all" and "men" ". The book is available for free at Archive.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first-order logic, $\forall$ cannot be considered a predicate for the fundamental reason that its *syntax* behaves completely differently from predicates.

A predicate is something that combines one or more *terms* into a *formula*.

In contrast $\forall$ combines a *variable name* and a *formula* into a new *formula*.

Because the syntax is not parallel, one cannot even write down rules or principles that apply in the same way for $\forall$ and predicates, so nothing would be gained by considering it one.

---

This holds equally for $\exists$, of course. In your argument you seem to be confusing "such-and-such particular thing (whose identity we somehow already agree on?) *exists*" with "there is something that has such-and-such properties". Formal logic's $\exists$ models the latter concept, not the former.

---

In *higher-order logic* we can phrase things such that $\forall$ becomes a predicate *on predicates*, which is true if the predicate we apply it to is the always-true predicate. Making this work probably requires having something like lambda abstractions in the syntax such that we can write down the predicates we apply $\forall$ to. There is impeccable historical precedent for this, but since the result is not a direct generalization of the usual syntax of first-order logic, it seems to be somewhat uncommon in "pure logic" theoretical treatments. (And computer proof systems such as HOL seem to prefer to go to a much *richer* type system where $\forall$ as well as its higher-order relatives are still primitive constructs).

Answer (score 1):

[The quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/) $\forall$ and $\exists$ are fundamental symbols - [originating towards the end of 19th Century](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-firstorder-emergence/) with [C.S. Peirce](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce/) and [G.Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) - that allow us to express in a formal manner basic sentences of natural language, like e.g.

> "Every Man is Mortal" : $\forall x ( \text {Man}(x) \to \text {Mortal}(x))$

and mathematics :

> "$0$ is not the *successor* of any natural number" : $\forall x \lnot (0=s(x))$.

---

In modern formulation of predicate logic, quantifiers are "special" symbols with specific syntactical rules governing them (and specific semantical rules to interpret them).

We use them **with** *terms* ("names" for objects) and *predicates* (denoting properties of objects) and *logical connectives* to form meaningful sentences (aka : *well-formed formulas*).

No one of the above "categories" of symbols is sufficient by itself to express sentences.

---

---

If you are interested, you can see a "special" type of logic : [Free Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/), where quantifiers (especially the existential one) are treated difefrently and you can have a "special" predicate $\text E !(x)$ for "actual" existence.

Comment: why wouldn't we write something like $(Man(x)\wedge \neg Mortal(x)) \rightarrow Doesntexist(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Here I understand " predicate" as a term that is applied to an individual ( a first level, concrete, individual, a " thing" ) and that attributes a property to this individual.

When you say " there is an x such that x has run a 100m race in less than 10 sec", you are not talking about a person, you are talking about a formula ( an open formula : " x has rum a 100m race .... " ) and say  that this formula is true for at least 1 value of the variable x. Or, if you prefer, you are talking about a set ( the set of all x such that x has run...) and say about this set ( not about a person) that this set is not empty.

From this follows that existence is not a predicate you attribute to things themselves ( existence is " being satisfied" for a formula or " non-emptiness" for a set).

In the same manner, when you use the universal quantifier, you do not talk about things, you talk about formulas or ( equivalently) about sets.

Using " for all x " ( belonging to some domain D) you say that an open formula with x as variable is satisfied for all values of the domain.

The following reasoning would count as a sophism:

(1) Musicians  are all artists. 
(2) Therfore Mozart is " all artist", Wagner is " all artist", etc.

or, even worse,

(1) Musicians are all artists. 
(2) Therefore, Mozart is all and Mozart is an arrtist, Wagner is all and Wagner is an artist, etc.

The word " all" does not refer to individuals as a predicate, it refers to the set of musicians and means that the whole set of musicians is included in the set of artists.

Answer (score 0):

You turn an $\exists$ into a $\forall$ by means of double negation.

$$\exists\,p:P(p)\iff\lnot\forall p:\lnot P(p).$$

It is a lie that all unicorns are inexistent.